# How to pass ARG value to ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry

Docker 1.9 allows to pass arguments to a dockerfile. See link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

How can i pass the same arugments within ENTRYPOINT Instruction??

My dockerfile has

> ARG $Version=3.1
>   ENTRYPOINT /tmp/folder-$Version/sample.sh start

I am getting an error while creating container with above dockerfile.
Please suggest what is the correct way to specify the argument within ENTRYPOINT instruction??

Comment: So you ask for the option, for example,  `--entrypoint=/root/run.sh`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Passing an argument Docker Entrypoint with entrypoint.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880367/docker-passing-an-argument-docker-entrypoint-with-entrypoint-sh)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Like *Blake Mitchell* sais, you cannot use `ARG` in `ENTRYPOINT`. However you can use your `ARG` as a value for `ENV`, that way you can use it with `ENTRYPOINT`:

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG my_arg
ENV my_env_var=$my_arg

ENTRYPOINT echo $my_env_var
```

and  run:

```
docker build --build-arg "my_arg=foo" ...
```

Comment: There's no workaround that will work in single executable containers, I suppose?

Comment: If you don't have the echo command this will not work.

Comment: Worked for me! thumbs up!

Comment: How is this different from declaring only `ENV` instead of both `ARG` and `ENV` if the value is going to be same? I will still be able to override the `ENV` in `docker run`

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this works because the ENTRYPOINT is in shell form, which does variable substitution. This won't work if you have the ENTRYPOINT in exec form.

Answer (score 42):

Short answer: you need to use `ENV`

Both `ARG` and `ENV` are not expanded in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) However, because `ENV`s are passed in as part of the environment, they are available at run time, so the shell can expand them. (This means you can't use the array form of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.)

Here is an example:

```
$ cat arg/Dockerfile
FROM debian:jessie
ARG FOO=bar
ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
$ sudo docker build arg
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> f50f9524513f
Step 2 : ARG FOO=bar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cfdcb514b62
Step 3 : ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
 ---> Running in 21fb9b42c10d
 ---> 75e5018bad83
Removing intermediate container 21fb9b42c10d
Successfully built 75e5018bad83
$ sudo docker run 75e5018bad83
foo
$ sudo docker run -e FOO=bas 75e5018bad83
bas
$ sudo docker build --build-arg FOO=bas arg
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> f50f9524513f
Step 2 : ARG FOO=bar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cfdcb514b62
Step 3 : ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 75e5018bad83
Successfully built 75e5018bad83
$ sudo docker run 75e5018bad83
foo
$ cat env/Dockerfile
FROM debian:jessie
ARG FOO=bar
ENV FOO=${FOO}
ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
$ sudo docker build env
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> f50f9524513f
Step 2 : ARG FOO=bar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cfdcb514b62
Step 3 : ENV FOO ${FOO}
 ---> Running in f157a07c1b3e
 ---> a5e8c5b65a17
Removing intermediate container f157a07c1b3e
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
 ---> Running in 66e9800ef403
 ---> 249fe326e9ce
Removing intermediate container 66e9800ef403
Successfully built 249fe326e9ce
$ sudo docker run 249fe326e9ce
bar
$ sudo docker run -e FOO=bas 249fe326e9ce
bas
$ sudo docker build --build-arg FOO=bas env
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> f50f9524513f
Step 2 : ARG FOO=bar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cfdcb514b62
Step 3 : ENV FOO ${FOO}
 ---> Running in 6baf31684b9f
 ---> 8f77ad154798
Removing intermediate container 6baf31684b9f
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT echo ${FOO:-foo}
 ---> Running in 892ac47cabed
 ---> fa97da85bf8a
Removing intermediate container 892ac47cabed
Successfully built fa97da85bf8a
$ sudo docker run fa97da85bf8a
bas
$
```

Comment: Why the environment variables are available at run time? Is the "run process" a child process of the build one?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case you have more than one parameter to pass to ENTRYPOINT or CMD, you can do like that:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG PROFILE
ENV PROFILE=${PROFILE}
...
CMD java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$(echo ${PROFILE}) /app/server.jar
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm struggling with this for a day, thanks for @Rotareti for mentioning. It needs to be in `ENV` before it can be used to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
ENV variable=$from_ARG_variable
ENTRYPOINT exec your_exec_sh_file $variable
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Spent some time scratching my head on the same issue. The ARG should be put to an ENV to be used in ENTRYPOINT. +1

Answer (score -3):

The syntax for `ARG` should omit the `$`.

Instead of `ARG $Version=3.1`, try `ARG Version=3.1`.