# Docker Passing an argument Docker Entrypoint with entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, devops

I tried to pass an argument to my docker entry point , but it fails ,
these are steps i followed

```
Docker Build Command : docker build -t "DBDNS" --build-arg  db=sample
```

In Dockerfile

```
ARG db
ENV database ${db}
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker/entrypoint.sh", ${db}]
```

Error for this
bash: 1: bash: [/var/www/html/.docker/entrypoint.sh,: not found

Actually file exists and passing an argument for entrypoint.sh causing issue.
Any clues for this

```
-----------ENTRYPOINT---------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Entrypoint stuff"
echo "----------------"
echo "NEW APP DB CLONE FROM  $1"
echo "sites/files permission changes"
echo "--------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Could you share `entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: Can you provide the ADD command where you add the entrypoint.sh file to the image?

Comment: @fzgregor updated in the question

Comment: @yamenK yeah i have done it already . without passing argument in 
 ENTRYPOINT ["/docker/entrypoint.sh", ${db}]
It works . but if i add the argument then only error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entrypoint cannot have a a variable. You can either move it to CMD or directly access it in `docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
ARG db
ENV database ${db}
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["${db}"]


-----------ENTRYPOINT---------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Entrypoint stuff"
echo "----------------"
echo "NEW APP DB CLONE FROM  $1 or same as $database"
echo "sites/files permission changes"
echo "--------------------------------------"
```

Even if you don't use CMD, `$database` will get you the value you need

Comment: It worked. thanks alot man.