# windows docker-compose args not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use args in a docker compose file.

The docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: test
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        entry: 1
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/test
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5
ARG entry
WORKDIR C:\\test
ADD ["/bin/x86/Release/","C:/test/"] 
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\test\\file.exe",  ${entry}]
```

I don't know how exactly works the syntax in the docker file. How I have to put the arg in the `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using it right. Try adding `RUN echo ${entry}` between the `ADD` and `ENTRYPOINT` directives to see whether it is being passed OK (temporarily for debufg purposes). In case it is, I would focus on what does `file.exe` do with a parameter provided like this. Isn't there a possibility it already works OK? Perhaps try to wrap the variable it into double-quotes..

Comment: Sorry @helvete, I forgot to say that I'm using docker for Windows. In this environment is like `RUN echo %entry%` for debug. The arguments have the correct value. Now I'm focusing on the `ENTRYPOINT`. I'm trying to pass the `ARG` to an `ENV` as @jannis says. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5

ARG ENTRY
ENV my_env=$ENTRY

#RUN echo %ENTRY%
#RUN echo %my_env%

WORKDIR C:\\test
ADD ["/bin/x86/Release/","C:/test/"]

ENTRYPOINT C:/test/file.exe %my_env%
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ARG` in `ENTRYPOINT` (at least not directly). See [How to pass ARG value to ENTRYPOINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324277/how-to-pass-arg-value-to-entrypoint):

> Both ARG and ENV are not expanded in ENTRYPOINT or CMD. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) However, because ENVs are passed in as part of the environment, they are available at run time, so the shell can expand them. (This means you can't use the array form of ENTRYPOINT or CMD.)