# Spring boot - Jasypt - Dockerfile - Build - how to pass environemnt variables

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am following spring io article on how to use docker for spring boot. So using Dockerfile
https://github.com/spring-guides/top-spring-boot-docker/tree/main/demo

**Issue**: Test failing

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
> PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178

My application has a few environment variables dependency

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=${mjasypt.secret}
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=${mjasypt.algo}
```

I am running build as below

```
docker build --build-arg DEPENDENCY=build/dependency -t ....
```

I tried  3 new env args into dockerfile

```
ARG CBS=a
ARG JSP=b
ARG JSA=c
```

and update entry point

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-noverify","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1","-cp","app:app/lib/*","-Dspring.main.lazy-initialization=true","-Dv1=${CBS}", "-Dv2=${JSP}", "-Dv3=${JSA}",...
```

and running command as, but didn't work

```
docker build --build-arg DEPENDENCY=build/dependency --build-arg CBS=.. --build-arg JSP=..1 --build-arg JSA=P..ES -t ...
```

Ive added **RUN echo ${CBS}** in the dockerfile and I can see the value that I passed from docker build (not a), but how can I know if that is inside ENTRY POINT too

**CORRECTION:**
Dockerfile is multistage and also has

> RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew clean build

How can I pass values to this command , as it runs tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ARG` in Dockerfile is only available in the build stage.

When you want to run it as a container, `ARG` values will not be available but `ENV` will be. This means you can not directly access those values in `ENTRYPOINT` (also not available in `CMD`). You can read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324277/how-to-pass-arg-value-to-entrypoint) for more info.

If you want to pass environment parameters to the container using the build arguments (`ARG`), the simple solution will be to do something like this:

```sh
ARG CBS=a
ARG JSP=b
ARG JSA=c

ENV CBS_ENV=$CBS
ENV JSP_ENV=$JSP
ENV JSA_ENV=$JSA
```

Then update your `ENTRYPOINT`

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-noverify","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1","-cp","app:app/lib/*","-Dspring.main.lazy-initialization=true","-Dv1=${CBS_ENV}", "-Dv2=${JSP_ENV}", "-Dv3=${JSA_ENV}",...
```

If your values are only used when the container is running, then you can remove `ARG` entirely, and pass it as arguments when the container is starting. Read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers) for more info.

e.g.:

```sh
docker run -e CBS='a' -e JSP='b' -e JSA='c' mynicevue
```

#### UPDATE:

```sh
ARG CBS=a
ARG JSP=b
ARG JSA=c

# First stage
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /workspace/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew clean build

RUN mkdir -p build/dependency && (cd build/dependency; jar -xf ../libs/*.jar)

# Second stage
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/dependency

ARG CBS
ARG JSP
ARG JSA

ENV CBS=$CBS
ENV JSP=$JSP
ENV JSA=$JSA

COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib

COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF

COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app 

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "app:app/lib/*", "hello.Application", "-Dv1=${CBS}", "-Dv2=${JSP}", "-Dv3=${JSA}"]
```

Comment: my starting point is "docker build ...." , so can you tell how to. Example dockerfile 
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /workspace/app
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew clean build
RUN mkdir -p build/dependency && (cd build/dependency; jar -xf ../libs/*.jar)

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]

Comment: If you need to use only `docker build` and you have multi-stage builds, you need to define `ARG` in global scope before any `FROM` commands. And in the stage that you want to use the value, again define `ARG`. The rest is similar to my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with the Dockerfile content you sent in the comment. I tried to add the 3 environment variables you had in the original question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer as it was very helpful (though I think there could be my fault with commands too)