# How to Pass environment as argument for a spring boot docker image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I created a docker file like this

```
ARG ENV
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV}", "app.jar"]
```

while doing
`docker run -p 8100:8080 anupbiswas1984/docker-env --e ENV=test`

it is not identifying `${ENV}`

How can I pass the ENV as an argument during "`docker run...`"

Comment: `ENV` (for an `ARG`) is no good identifier in docker ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass ARG value to ENTRYPOINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324277/how-to-pass-arg-value-to-entrypoint)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `ARG` thing, as it's not needed and you aren't using it correctly anyway. Per [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command

So `ARG` is a build-time thing, and you are trying to use it as a run-time environment variable.

Also, you can get rid of the `"-Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV}"` part of your `ENTRYPOINT` because Spring Boot already looks for an environment variable named `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` so there's no need to define another thing here, and you're also introducing an issue with the way you are trying to resolve the `ENV` variable here.

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Then run it with:

```
docker run -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test -p 8100:8080 anupbiswas1984/docker-env
```